# .NET video play library which allows to change the playback rate?

Tags: c#, .net, video, playback

I am integrating a video player to an existing .NET WinForms application.

I first tried to use "Windows Media Player Control" which is included in Windows SDK,
but I could not change the playback rate.

The following is the code I wrote to change the rate.

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.get_isAvailable("Rate"))
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = 3.0;
}
```

The condition in the if statement always returns "false" no matter what video file I use. Does anyone have any idea why I cannot change the rate? It really needs to be available to change the playback rate, so WMP control seems to be a bad choice if it's impossible to do so.

Or, is there any alternative solution which allows me to change the rate? Preferably a .NET based library which does not involve any unmanaged code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using DirectShow.NET (http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) which is an open-source library. It contains a lot of samples, and it has a sample with playback rate control.

Answer (score 0):

IF a commercial library is an option take a look at http://www.visioforge.com/media-player-sdk-net.html

Another commercial option would be Leadtools MultIMedia SDK - see http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia.htm#+cp_playback

Comment: Thanks for pointing useful resources, but a commercial one should be the last resort in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Is the if statement really necessary?
I could set the rate fine without it..

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = 3.0;